# How to Skip Header from Excel Spreadsheet While Uploading to MySQL

Tags: php, excel

**Is it possible by code to skip the Header (Top Row) in Excel Spreadsheet?
I'm using PHPExcel_Reader to process upload into database.**

[this image is my data excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXpiV.png)

*this is my code:*

```
<?php require_once('../../php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php'); require_once('../../SpreadsheetReader.php'); if (isset($_POST["import"])) { $allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet']; if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){ $targetPath = '../assets/uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name']; move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath); $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath); $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets()); for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++) { $Reader->ChangeSheet($i); foreach ($Reader as $Row) { $student_id = ""; if(isset($Row[0])) { $student_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[0]); } $roll_no = ""; if(isset($Row[1])) { $roll_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[1]); } $student_name = ""; if(isset($Row[2])) { $student_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[2]); } $class_name = ""; if(isset($Row[3])) { $class_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[3]); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method for skip header :

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('FILE.xlsx');
$sheetData = array();

foreach ($spreadsheet->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
        for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
            $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $val = $cell->getValue();
            $sheetData[$row][$col] = $val;
        }
    }
}

unset($sheetData[1]); // SKIP HEADER

foreach ($sheetData as $val) {
  // set data for upload DB
 }
```

i just unset that from array.

Comment: thanks this work but i want to use librairy php spreadsheet-reader-master not phpExcel

Comment: as you can see `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet`  is phpspreadsheet not phpexcel.